# Execute operation on Laravel Eloquent associate

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way to execute some code on Associate?

For example I would like to execute some operation where a `Dog` is associated to a `Man` with `$dog->man()->associate($man);`, is it possibile?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "execute some code"?

Comment: I've a variable that must be updated on associating, I know that it is a "structural error" but this don't depends on me.

For example set $dog->ownerNationality = $man->nationality;